# setting sample_weight_mode="temporal" doesn't seem to work

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am working with LSTM in tensorflow 2.0 and I am trying to assign a weight to the training samples (I've already tried with class_weights dictionary but it complains that 3-d arrays are not supported for it. my array shape is (26000, 7, 1)).

As suggested in the documentation, I am setting sample_weight_mode to "temporal" in compile, but after that when I try to fit the model I still get the error below:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-100-1bb94008291c> in <module>
      1 with tf.device("/device:GPU:0"):
----> 2     model.fit(X, y, epochs=500, batch_size=4096, verbose=1, validation_split=0.2, sample_weight=cw.reshape(26000,7,1))

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\thesis-gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, **kwargs)
    641         max_queue_size=max_queue_size,
    642         workers=workers,
--> 643         use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing)
    644 
    645   def evaluate(self,

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\thesis-gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training_arrays.py in fit(self, model, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_freq, **kwargs)
    630         steps=steps_per_epoch,
    631         validation_split=validation_split,
--> 632         shuffle=shuffle)
    633 
    634     if validation_data:

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\thesis-gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py in _standardize_user_data(self, x, y, sample_weight, class_weight, batch_size, check_steps, steps_name, steps, validation_split, shuffle, extract_tensors_from_dataset)
   2459           training_utils.standardize_weights(ref, sw, cw, mode)
   2460           for (ref, sw, cw, mode) in zip(y, sample_weights, class_weights,
-> 2461                                          feed_sample_weight_modes)
   2462       ]
   2463       # Check that all arrays have the same length.

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\thesis-gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py in <listcomp>(.0)
   2458       sample_weights = [
   2459           training_utils.standardize_weights(ref, sw, cw, mode)
-> 2460           for (ref, sw, cw, mode) in zip(y, sample_weights, class_weights,
   2461                                          feed_sample_weight_modes)
   2462       ]

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\thesis-gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training_utils.py in standardize_weights(y, sample_weight, class_weight, sample_weight_mode)
    839     if sample_weight is not None and len(sample_weight.shape) != 1:
    840       raise ValueError('Found a sample_weight array with shape ' +
--> 841                        str(sample_weight.shape) + '. '
    842                        'In order to use timestep-wise sample weights, '
    843                        'you should specify '

ValueError: Found a sample_weight array with shape (26000, 7, 1). In order to use timestep-wise sample weights, you should specify sample_weight_mode="temporal" in compile(). If you just mean to use sample-wise weights, make sure your sample_weight array is 1D.
```

I have already tried changing the shape of the sample_weights passed in fit (also tried to flatten it), setting shuffle to False and removing the validation split without success.

Here's the code I am using

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math

# Import TensorFlow
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import RMSprop, Adam, SGD
from tensorflow.keras.layers import SimpleRNN, LSTM, Dense
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential

from sklearn.utils import class_weight

class_weights = class_weight.compute_class_weight('balanced',
                                                 np.unique(y_train),
                                                 y_train)

cw = class_weight.compute_sample_weight({False:1, True:50},#'balanced',
                                                 #np.unique(y_train),
                                                 y.flatten())

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(160, return_sequences=True, dropout=0.05))
model.add(LSTM(80, return_sequences=True, dropout=0.05, activation='relu'))
model.add(LSTM(40, return_sequences=True, dropout=0.05, activation='relu'))
model.add(LSTM(10, return_sequences=True, dropout=0.05))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['acc', tf.keras.metrics.AUC()], sample_weight_mode="temporal")

with tf.device("/device:GPU:0"):
    model.fit(X, y, epochs=500, batch_size=4096, verbose=1, validation_split=0.2, sample_weight=cw.reshape(26000,7,1))
```

Answer (score 1):

Sample weighting applies to outputs (because what you are weighting is the loss!), not inputs, so it doesn't matter what your input dimensions are. The error message is explicitly about output dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

The dimension of `sample_weight` cannot be greater than 2. If `sample_weight_mode` in the `compile` function is `None`, then `sample_weight` must be 1 dimensional. If `sample_weight_mode` in the `compile` function is `'temporal'`, then `sample_weight` must be 2 dimensional.
Additionally, it is always be true that `y.shape[:sample_weight.ndim] == sample_weight.shape`.
For more details, please refer to the source code of `keras.engine.training_utils.standardize_weights`.